# NETTE-LATTE: Include on click

Tags: javascript, ajax, nette, latte

I have a question. Can somebody explain me, how can I include another .latte file and send dynamic data with it?

I am creating api function, where you should be able to get information about company just by writing it's name. When I click to search, I can see in console that my request is getting through and sending back response, with correct data, but it won't refresh already loaded data.

Some examples of my code:

**Javascript:**

```
btn.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
var firma = $("#firmaName").val();

console.log( "var is " + firma );

$.ajax('data', {
    data: { 'firma' : firma}

});

}
```

**.latte**

```
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>

            {include 'data.latte'}  

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, you are not doing anything with the data in your javascript code. One way to do this simply would be to use [snippets](https://doc.nette.org/en/3.1/ajax), e.g. [with Naja](https://naja.js.org/#/snippets). That way, just by submitting the form, the appropriate page of the page would be automatically updated using AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

best way to approach this is by snippets and $.netteAjax().

viz: https://doc.nette.org/en/application/ajax

also, include tag can accept parameters, which are then used within loaded template, like here: https://latte.nette.org/cs/tags#toc-include

I also would recomend, insted of using include of antoher latte file, I would create component for your modal, viz. https://doc.nette.org/en/application/components